# How to vertically align text in a div next to another div containing a select element

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I want to vertically align "text" with the select element. They both need to be inside separate divs. Is this possible?

```
<fieldset>
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left;vertical-align:middle">
    text
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block;float:left">
    <select>
        <option>select
        </option>
    </select>
    properly aligned
</div>
</fieldset>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ATN8n/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your texts are both in separate divs, these 2 divs should have the same height, then we have to change the `vertical-align` accordingly like this:

```
<div style="display:inline-block; float:left; height: 30px;">
    text
</div>
<div style="display:inline-block; float:left; height:30px;">
    <select>
        <option>select
        </option>
    </select>            
</div>

div:before {
 content:'';
 display:inline-block;
 height:100%;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATN8n/8/)

Comment: I think this is the right solution but I'm not sure I understand it. We're inserting a hidden element before each div to trick vertical alignment?

Comment: @allenylzhou something like that, however as I said the 2 divs need to have the same height or you can find another way in which the 2 divs will have another div as the same container, then apply the vertical-align to the 2 divs

Comment: @allenylzhou using `float` as you did is the cause of your problem, the `float` will take the elements out of document flow and you can't control their alignment, setting them to the same height is just a trick, so you can try another approach such as don't use float ...

Comment: I understand. I need to use float because I want them to wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your text in a span tag like this:

```
<span>text</span>
```

then style it like this:

```
span {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

edit:  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATN8n/7/)

Comment: this seemed to have worked with my example. but it doesn't work in general. I just have to increase the size of the select element a little bit and it will be misaligned again.